# Python quit unexpectedly while using the libhdf5.103.dylib plug-in

Tags: python, keras

I have a trained machine learning model named model.h5. I am using Keras to load model as

```
>>> from keras.models import load_model
>>> model=load_model("model.h5")
```

But the following error message gets printed.

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

And then a pop-up occurs which says

```
Python quit unexpectedly while using the libhdf5.103.dylib plug-in.
```

On my Linux machine, the code is working and the model is loading, but on my Mac, the described error occurs. I am using Python 2.7.10.

Comment: Are you using multithreading by chance? I've had problems with the default build of HDF with multithreading (specifically using the Django debug server, which is multithreaded).

Comment: I am using Flask. And the model is trained on Google Colabs. I am not sure if it is multithreaded (sorry but I am novice :( ).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running with Flask, your problem is likely that by default Flask uses a multi-threaded debug server (when you run `flask run`), and HDF doesn't support multi-threading by default.

The easiest fix is to simply turn off multithreading for your flask server:

```
flask run --without-threads
```

You can also build HDF with threading support, but that's more difficult and not entirely supported. In production, this usually isn't a problem, because production WSGI servers use multiprocessing instead of multithreading.

Comment: I tried this, but it still shows "Segmentation fault: 11". I also ran the code in python interactive mode and at line 

    >>> model=load_model("model.h5")
it shows the error and python quites.

Comment: How did you install HDF5?

Comment: Ah, perhaps got installed along with something else. Are you using homebrew?

Comment: Python 2.7.10 is by default installed in MacOS. And I think HDF5 installed along with Tensorflow or Keras.

Comment: Ah, ok. I don't have experience with the Tensorflow-included HDF5 (if that is where it came from). I've used Homebrew's HDF5 (which works fine single-threaded), and a custom-built version for multi-threading. It wouldn't hurt to install HDF5 with Homebrew and see if it makes a difference (make sure it's used instead of the other one).